# What should be the correct formula to find the overall literacy rate?

Tags: statistics, average

I need to find the overall literacy rate for the 12 slum pockets. The total population including all 12 pockets is 1888.

[click link for the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74pGb.png)

The data above shows the original male and female population and the literacy rate of the male and female of each of the 12 slum pockets. What would be the correct statistical way to find out the overall literacy rate of all the 12 slums. The equations that I considered were:

1. $$\begin{multline}\text{Overall basic literacy rate of all the slum pockets} \\
   = \frac{\text{Overall literacy rate of slum population surveyed}}{\text{Overall slum population surveyed}} \times 100\% \end{multline}$$
2. $$\text{Overall basic literacy rate of all the slum pockets} = \frac{1}{n}  ∑_{i=1}^na_i$$

Which formula is correct?

Comment: What are your $a_i$? Possibly related question: [Why is an average of an average usually incorrect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect/95912)

Comment: Why is at least one of your literacy rates over $100$? I initially assumed those were percentages. If they are absolute numbers, it's an even easier problem, but you shouldn't call those "rates".

Comment: Make the image visible by typing `![click link for the data][1]
`